# Why Tachibana Hibiki's moves have no name?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

In Symphogear every move except Tachibana Hibiki's have a name and a "poster" animation.

Why only hers do not have names?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's because she's the only one who doesn't manifest an Armed Gear (except at season-end for Synchrogazer/etc), but I can't find supporting evidence in any of the keywords.

Comment: @senshin Isn't her Armed Gear her fists? The move where she turns on the "turbines" on her arm, extends backwards and thrusts forward was used at least twice in each season. Also the S2CA burst, etc. But you are right, on season finales, their combined moves do have a splash poster.

Answer (score -1):

Hibiki is not having her attacks in a "poster" as (due to S1 events) she was part-Gungnir. Hence, her attacks are by itself is the attack of the gear